# Using an external variable inside a function

Tags: php, function

I know title seems obscure but trust me I have researched this already but it fails for my code.

I have a code for licensing which pretty much looks like this

```
<?php if ( true ) : ?>
<?php print( 'Your License is Active' ); $type = 1; ?>
```

It pretty much sets the $type variable.

Now my problem:

```
function file_pull() {
if ( $type == 1 ) {
    $import_path = '/main/';

    $files_array = array(
        'start'               => array(),
        'home'                => array(
            'description' => __( 'Importing: Main Templates', 'kss' ),
            'files'       => array(
                'home.xml',
            ),
        ),

    );
}
if ( $type == 2 ) {
    $import_path = '/main/';

    $files_array = array(
        'start'               => array(),
        'home'                => array(
            'description' => __( 'Importing: Main Templates', 'kss' ),
            'files'       => array(
                'page1.xml',
            ),
        ),

    );
}
```

}

How can I use the $type variable inside this function so that it runs these file pull requests?

I have tried global to no avail. I have also tried setting it as a parameter.

```
function file_pull($type) {
```

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Are you setting the $type and then calling the function in the same request?
2. Can you put var_dump($type); inside file_pull function (just above the first if) and post the result?

Comment: you need to set `$type` before you call the function.

Comment: `function file_pull($type) {` is the way to go, but be aware that `$type` in this case does not automatically use your `$type` from outside the function. You'd need to call the function like `file_pull(1)` or `file_pull(2)`

Comment: Just to add on to @kerbholz's comment (which I also believe is the best solution to this question) `$type` is out of scope from your function. Have a read of the [documentation on function scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to get a better grasp on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `function file_pull($type) {` is a good start. Change your function to:

```
function file_pull($typeParam) {
    if ( $typeParam == 1 ) {
        $import_path = '/main/';

        $files_array = array(
            'start'               => array(),
            'home'                => array(
                'description' => __( 'Importing: Main Templates', 'kss' ),
                'files'       => array(
                    'home.xml',
                ),
            ),

        );
    }
    if ( $typeParam == 2 ) {
        $import_path = '/main/';

        $files_array = array(
            'start'               => array(),
            'home'                => array(
                'description' => __( 'Importing: Main Templates', 'kss' ),
                'files'       => array(
                    'page1.xml',
                ),
            ),

        );
    }
}
```

This way you can call it like:

```
$type=1;
file_pull($type);
```

I used `$typeParam` as function parameter to not get confused with your `$type` outside your function.

Comment: Not sure who you're talking about when saying about *confusion* but PHP won't get confused if `file_pull` requires `$type`. The OP's code likely didn't work before because he probably didn't call `file_pull($type);`. Anyway, this wins my upvote as it's the solution I was hoping for.

Comment: I meant OP maybe getting confused about two `$type`s there